# How to change or overwrite order_id number in Magento store URL?

Tags: magento2, orders, url, customer-account, url-rewrite

When viewing orders as customer order_id is visible in URL like this: /sales/order/view/**order_id**/**20**/

Is it possible to achieve that orders would be accessible by increment_id value instead? Otherwise there's not much sense in changing increment_id (order number) if customers are still able to see order_id values, so they still know how many orders and at what pace store is getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the URL from the sales template to add increment_id. After that, you can try the following changes, allowing you to load the order by increment_id instead of ID.

app/code/Vendor/Sales/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoader">
        <plugin name="order_load_by_increment_id" type="Vendor\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoader" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**And now:**

app/code/Vendor/Sales/Controller/AbstractController/OrderLoader.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Sales\Controller\AbstractController;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoader as BaseOrderLoader;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;

class OrderLoader
{
    /**
     * @param OrderFactory $orderFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        private OrderFactory $orderFactory
    ) {

    }

    /**
     * @param BaseOrderLoader $subject
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function beforeLoad(
        BaseOrderLoader $subject,
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $orderId = $request->getParam('order_id');
        if ($orderId) {
            $order = $this->orderFactory->create();
            $order = $order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
            if ($order && $order->getId()) {
                $request->setParam('order_id', $order->getId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code allows to get orders by increment_id, thanks for that. Yet orders may be accessed by order_id and some modifications to generating links under customer account to orders needed to insert increment_id in URL instead of order_id. I'll check that.